Issue with gRPC calling using nginx
I am using golang for implementing gRPC. So normally when a gRPC client establishes the connection with the gRPC server it uses “IP:Port” in the dial function.
But I want to use "domain-name" instead of calling my server using IP:port .
Attached below is the diagram that explains the calling

GRPC for our domain dev-abc.indiamart.com which is running on port 3000 ( and this is going to be our internal domain )
And this will be called from our global domain i.e. open to users let's say dev-global.indiamart.com.
(HTTPS enabled and HTTP/1.1 protocol supported) dev-global.indiamart.com and a gRPC client running on thi -------> Nginx(HTTP only and HTTP/2.0 protocol supported)  -----> Redirect on dev-abc.indiamart.com(Running on 3000 port).
Therefore we want to set it up on (HTTP) for which we have written the below nginx configuration.
`    # For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 http2 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root    path-to-repo;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/abc_access.log  main;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

        location / {
             grpc_pass grpc://dev-abc.indiamart.com:3000;
        }
}`

Post setup of nginx when I am trying to connect to a gRPC server using domain dev-abc.indiamart.com, so the request is not getting initiated.
But if I use port 80 along with the domain i.e “dev-abc.indiamart.com:80”, then the connection is established successfully using dial function and we get to see following logs in nginx log file :
121.241.18.212 - - [04/Apr/2024:23:39:15 +0530] "POST /PDP.PDP/GetProductDetails HTTP/2.0" 200 10966 "-" "grpc-node-js/1.8.10" "-"
I have referred to the following article - https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/ (though I have tried the ssl configuration too but in my case I don't want to use TLS)
Why am I doing wrong here as I need to use port 80 explicitly with my domain for a successful gRPC call?
